# XSLT: Sorting nodes by attribute and grouping child

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, grouping

I have to sort and group a certain node and subnodes in my xml by an attribute

given xml:

```
<Rechnung>
<somenodes />
<RechnungArtikelLieferinfos>
    <RechnungArtikelLieferinfo InfoTypLangtext="Folgende Artikel sind vergriffen und leider nicht mehr nachlieferbar:" InfoTypKurztext="NICHT_NACHLIEFERBAR" InfoTyp="2">
        <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Beilage" ArtikeltypId="9" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="12345" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Angebotsblatt someone de" Katalogkennzeichen="99"/>
    </RechnungArtikelLieferinfo>
    <RechnungArtikelLieferinfo InfoTypLangtext="Folgende Artikel sind im Rückstand:" InfoTypKurztext="RÜCKSTAND" InfoTyp="3">
        <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Beilage" ArtikeltypId="9" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="12345" Bestellmenge="2.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Angebotsblatt someoneother de" Katalogkennzeichen="99"/>
    </RechnungArtikelLieferinfo>          
    <RechnungArtikelLieferinfo InfoTypLangtext="Folgende Artikel sind vergriffen und leider nicht mehr nachlieferbar:" InfoTypKurztext="NICHT_NACHLIEFERBAR" InfoTyp="2">
        <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Beilage" ArtikeltypId="9" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="54321" Bestellmenge="2.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Angebotsblatt something de" Katalogkennzeichen="99"/>
    </RechnungArtikelLieferinfo>  
    <RechnungArtikelLieferinfo InfoTypLangtext="Folgende Artikel sind im Rückstand:" InfoTypKurztext="NICHT_AUF_LAGER" InfoTyp="0">
        <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Beilage" ArtikeltypId="9" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="5555" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="some article" Katalogkennzeichen="99"/>
    </RechnungArtikelLieferinfo>    
</RechnungArtikelLieferinfos>
<somemorenodes />
</Rechnung>
```

RechnungArtikelLieferinfo is to be sorted by its attribute @Infotyp. On the same RechnungArtikelLieferinfo@Infotyp the Artikelposition-Nodes should be grouped (I hope I'm nmaking sense here, english is not my first language)

expected result:

```
<Rechnung>
<somenodes />
<RechnungArtikelLieferinfos>
    <RechnungArtikelLieferinfo InfoTypLangtext="Folgende Artikel sind im Rückstand:" InfoTypKurztext="NICHT_AUF_LAGER" InfoTyp="0">
        <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Beilage" ArtikeltypId="9" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="5555" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="some article" Katalogkennzeichen="99"/>
    </RechnungArtikelLieferinfo>  
    <RechnungArtikelLieferinfo InfoTypLangtext="Folgende Artikel sind vergriffen und leider nicht mehr nachlieferbar:" InfoTypKurztext="NICHT_NACHLIEFERBAR" InfoTyp="2">
        <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Beilage" ArtikeltypId="9" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="12345" Bestellmenge="1.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Angebotsblatt someone de" Katalogkennzeichen="99"/>
        <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="something" ArtikeltypId="9" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="54321" Bestellmenge="2.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Angebotsblatt something de" Katalogkennzeichen="99"/>
    </RechnungArtikelLieferinfo>
    <RechnungArtikelLieferinfo InfoTypLangtext="Folgende Artikel sind im Rückstand:" InfoTypKurztext="RÜCKSTAND" InfoTyp="3">
        <Artikelposition Absagekennzeichen="Allein im Rückstand" AbsagekennzeichenId="38" Artikeltyp="Beilage" ArtikeltypId="9" Zusatztextkennzeichen="" Zusatztext="" Bestellnummer="44444" Bestellmenge="2.00" Artikelbezeichnung="Angebotsblatt someoneother de" Katalogkennzeichen="99"/>
    </RechnungArtikelLieferinfo>  
</RechnungArtikelLieferinfos>
<somemorenodes />
</Rechnung>
```

I am new to XSL(T) and read quite some documentation about this. I guess the best way to do this would be using XSLT 2.0 with its grouping options (for-each-group), but I'm somewhat lost after all that reading and more confused than before. Especially as all tutorials assume that you have to reconstruct the structure and I just have to move nodes and childs around without changing them.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with just templates rather than for-each loops (normally best avoided in XSLT).

Runnable demo at [this XML Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/XhAqst) (see output source).

```
<!-- kick things off -->
<xsl:template match="Rechnung/RechnungArtikelLieferinfos">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='RechnungArtikelLieferinfo[not(preceding-sibling::RechnungArtikelLieferinfo/@InfoTyp = @InfoTyp)]'>
            <xsl:sort select='@InfoTyp' data-type='number' />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- RechnungArtikelLieferinfo nodes (unique only) -->
<xsl:template match='RechnungArtikelLieferinfo'>

    <!-- copy node, and... -->
    <xsl:copy>

        <!-- ...its attributes/text -->
        <xsl:copy-of select='@*|text()' />

        <!-- ...any Artikelposition nodes of same parent @InfoTyp -->
        <xsl:copy-of select='../RechnungArtikelLieferinfo[@InfoTyp = current()/@InfoTyp]/Artikelposition' />

    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: you can avoid the xsl:if by use of a predicate on your match expression.

Comment: Of course, I was just trying to be explicit as he said he was new to it. In hindsight, it is better practised. +1. Edited.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not work.


First Editix says 


"Attribute @type is not allowed on element xsl:sort".


Second only one RechnungArtikelLieferinfo is written into the target  xml instead of all of them.


Thanks again

Comment: Care to elaborate? See the playground session. The output XML is what you said you wanted.

Comment: solved the first error myself: it should be "data-type" not "type" on the xsl:sort

Comment: Whilst this is true, the output was *nonetheless* what you required, since the default type for sorting is text, and 0, 2, 3 would therefore end up in that order anyway. I provided an answer, you might consider just a little gratitude.

Comment: Well, I **did** already thank you twice, so to me I do not seem to be ungrateful.

I now had a look into the output on XMLPlayground. The output there differs from the one I get in Editix. Sorry about my remark that it does not work. It seems not to work in my Editor. Will try in Eclipse.

Comment: In Eclipse this also does not work. Will attach the resulting XML to the question

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem seems to be resulting from the part of the XML-source that was shortened by me as <somenodes /> and <somemorenodes />

So I guess the solution is correct, just not for my real xml-file. I try to understand what is done in the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Would someone care to explain the XPath-Expression 'RechnungArtikelLieferinfo[not(preceding-sibling::RechnungArtikelLieferinfo/@InfoTyp = @InfoTyp)]' to me? This seems to filter out any multiple occurances of @InfoTyp resulting in <Lieferinfo>s unique by @InfoTyp?

Comment: @Xanathon - yes, this is to ensure that only unique `RechnungArtikelLieferinfo` (unique being defined by their `@InfoTyp` node) nodes are transformed. The common way to do this is to use a preceding- or following-sibling axis to see if there's any behind or ahead of it with the same credentials, as I do here. Sorry for the confusion before - it's just I wrote a solution and I thought you'd ignored it over one, inconsequential mistake (`type` vs. `data-type`). Good luck with the rest of the project.